# React leaflet center attribute does not change when the center state changes

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

**App.js**

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  // This state is used to the center attribute of MapContainer component
  const [mapCenter, setMapCenter] = useState([34.80746, -40.4796]);
  // This state is used to the zoom attribute of MapContainer component
  const [mapZoom, setMapZoom] = useState(3);

  const onClickHandler = () => {
    setMapCenter([20, 100]);
    setMapZoom(5);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={onClickHandler}>Change map's center location</button>
      <Map center={mapCenter} zoom={mapZoom} />
    </>
  );
};
```

**Map.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Map.css';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';

function Map({ center, zoom }) {
  return (
    <div className="map">
      <MapContainer center={center} zoom={zoom}>
        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution='&copy; <a 
                href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        />
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Map;
```

**Map.css**

```css
.map {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.map .leaflet-container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

When I clicks button, mapCenter state clearly changes to [20, 100] and mapZoom also changes to 5. But in the Map Component Map does not show new center. but I don't know why. I already checked state's change.
Map never respond. Does anyone knows??? Please answer a way to figure it out.

Answer (score 39):

> Except for its `children`, `MapContainer` props are **immutable**: changing them after they have been set a first time will have no effect on the Map instance or its container.
> The Leaflet Map instance created by the MapContainer element can be accessed by child components using one of the provided hooks or the MapConsumer component.
> https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map

**ChangeView.js**

```
function ChangeView({ center, zoom }) {
  const map = useMap();
  map.setView(center, zoom);
  return null;
}
```

**Map.js**

```
function Map({ center, zoom }) {
  return (
    <div className="map">
      <MapContainer center={center} zoom={zoom} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
        <ChangeView center={center} zoom={zoom} /> 
        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        />
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The react-leaflet documentation uses `setCenter` in it's [useMapEvent example](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map/#usemapevent), but this function isn't defined. However in leaflets documentation *[Methods for modifying map state](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-setview)* there is a function `setView(center, zoom, options?)`.

Comment: It is so helpful. Thank you for your answer. I finally resolved it.

Comment: @Banny you can just render something else until you have the center coordinates. E.g. (like a loading animation)

Answer (score 5):

```
const Map = ({ center, zoom }) => {
  const [map, setmap] = useState(null);
  if (map) {
    map.flyTo(center);
  }
  return (
    <div className="map">
      <LeafletMap
        center={center}
        zoom={zoom}
        whenCreated={setmap}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
      >
        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        ></TileLayer>
      </LeafletMap>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! When answering a question, please include some commentary for the questioner and other readers to understand your solution.

Answer (score 2):

In your `Map` compontent for example `map.js` add this function:

```
const Recenter = ({lat,lng}) => {
        const map = useMap();
        useEffect(() => {
            map.setView([lat, lng]);
        }, [lat, lng]);
        return null;
    }
```

And call it inside your `MapContainer`:

```
export default function Map(props){

const [position, setPosition] = useState({ lat: 98.699739, lng: 52.338097 }); // set default position

useEffect(()=> {
        if(props.latlng){
            setPosition(props.latlng); // update via props
        }
    }, [props]);

/* other codes */

    <MapContainer center={position} zoom={14} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
       <Recenter lat={position.lat} lng={position.lng} />
    </MapContainer>
```

And here you can update new position with `setPosition` and it will automatically recenter map on `position` update.

Answer (score 1):

Instead You can use [map-flyto](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-flyto).

```
flyTo(<LatLng> latlng, <Number> zoom?, <Zoom/pan options> options?)
```

**Working Example**

```
import {
  MapContainer,
  TileLayer,
  useMap,
} from "react-leaflet";

// Used to recenter the map to new coordinates
const MapRecenter= ({ lat, lng, zoomLevel }) => {
  const map = useMap();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fly to that coordinates and set new zoom level
    map.flyTo([lat, lng], zoomLevel );
  }, [lat, lng]);
  return null;

};

// Render Map Component
function Map() {
 // Set initials
 const center = [30.375321, 69.345116]; 
 const zoom = 4;

  return (
    <div className="map">
      <MapContainer center={center} zoom={zoom}>
        {/* Cusotm Recenterig of Map component */} 
        {/* Pass New Cordinated and ZoomLevel */}       
        <MapRecenter lat={33.6712} lng={35.8277} zoomLevel={6} />
          <TileLayer
            noWrap={false}
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          />
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```