# React Leaflet - Update map center

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm using React Leaflet. I have a map and an array with names and corresponding positions. Every name from the array is a button. When I click on a name the position changes and should be updated in the map. That works with the marker but not with the section of the map. How can I update also the section of the map?

```
const data = [
      {
        name: 'John',
        coordinates: {
          langitude: '40.72260370101827',
          latitude: '-73.99323791583221',
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'Bob',
        coordinates: {
          langitude: '40.72843542344666',
          latitude: '-73.94860440141105',
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'Chris',
        coordinates: {
          langitude: '40.79159996340942',
          latitude: '-73.94077957876242',
        },
      },
    ];

export default function Map(props) {
  const { index, data } = props;

  return (
    <MapContainer
      center={[
        data[index].coordinates.langitude,
        data[index].coordinates.latitude,
      ]}
      zoom={16}
    >
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      ></TileLayer>
      <Marker
        position={[
          data[index].coordinates.langitude,
          data[index].coordinates.latitude,
        ]}
      >
        <Popup>{data[index].name}</Popup>
      </Marker>
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a complete description for this issue in: [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64665827/react-leaflet-center-attribute-does-not-change-when-the-center-state-changes). Basically the `center` prop (and all other props, except children) of `MapContainer` is immutable, so you need to use the provided methods as explained in the answer above.
However, here's a quick fix I thought of:

```
 <MapContainer
     key={JSON.stringify([data[index].coordinates.langitude, data[index].coordinates.latitude])}
     center={[
        data[index].coordinates.langitude,
        data[index].coordinates.latitude,
     ]}
     zoom={16}
>
```

Only addition to your code is the `key` prop, which takes the stringified center position. So when the position changes, another instance of the `MapContainer` component is created (a fresh copy ;) ), having the proper `center` value.

Comment: this is not the proper way to update the map view. It is more a hack rather than a proper solution.

Comment: @kboul you are right. That's why I wrote "a quick fix". The proper way to do it is in the link I so graciously put in the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: Here's more info on the "hack", if someone's curious: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key ... while that's a very specific use case (and OMG, back from the day they had `class`es in React), I personally prefer knowing of a tool, no matter how "hacky", than looking at it and wishing it never existed, because it's too ugly. Cheers ;)

Answer (score 3):

From the official [docs](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map):

> Except for its children, MapContainer props are **immutable**: changing
> them after they have been set a first time will have no effect on the
> Map instance or its container.

As a result you have to create a custom component that changes the map view upon coordinate change

```
function SetViewOnClick({ coords }) {
  const map = useMap();
  map.setView(coords, map.getZoom());

  return null;
}
```

Use it a child of MapContainer below your Marker comp by passing the coorinates as a prop.

```
<SetViewOnClick
        coords={[
          data[index].coordinates.langitude,
          data[index].coordinates.latitude
        ]}
/>
```

Once the updated index is received  map's view will be changed.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-v3x-update-map-center-9826u?file=/src/Map.jsx)