# How to set view of map for new location using latitute and longitude with React-leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, rest, react-leaflet

I am unable to set view of the map for the input IP address while the Marker can move to the new location on the map for given input IP address. Map seems to stay at initial location whereas the Marker moves to new location.

So, When I type in a new IP address in input, it should change the map to a new location.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from "react";
import Result from "../src/Components/Result";
import {MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';

function App() {
  const APP_KEY = PERSONAL_KEY;

  const [IPdata, SetIPData] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("8.8.8.8");
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);


  useEffect(() => {
    getIp();
    setLoaded(true);

  }, [query]);

  async function getIp() {
    const response = await fetch(`https://geo.ipify.org/api/v1?apiKey=${APP_KEY}&ipAddress=${query}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    SetIPData(data)
  }

  function handleChange(event) {
    setSearch(event.target.value);
    console.log(event.target.value);

  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setQuery(search);
    setSearch('');

  }

  return (
    loaded ? (
      <div>
        <div className="container">

          <div className="input-section">
            <h1 className="header"> IP Address Tracker</h1>

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="search-form">
              <input className="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search for any IP address or domain" onChange={handleChange} />
              <button className="search-button" type="submit"> Go! </button>
            </form>

          </div>

          <div className="result-container">

            <Result
              heading={"IP Address"}
              searchResult={IPdata.ip}
            />

            <Result
              heading={"Location"}
              searchResult={IPdata?.location?.country}
            />

            <Result
              heading={"Timezone"}
              searchResult={"UTC" + IPdata?.location?.timezone}
            />

            <Result
              heading={"ISP"}
              searchResult={IPdata.isp}
            />

          </div>

        </div>

        {IPdata.location && (


          <MapContainer
            center={[IPdata.location?.lat, IPdata.location?.lng]}
            zoom={13}
            scrollWheelZoom={true}

          >
            <TileLayer
              attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
              url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            <Marker position={[IPdata?.location?.lat, IPdata?.location?.lng]}>
              <Popup>Your IP Location</Popup>
            </Marker>
          </MapContainer>
        )
        }

      </div>) : <p>Loading...</p>

  )

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the center with state because of this...

> Except for its children, MapContainer props are immutable: changing
> them after they have been set a first time will have no effect on the
> Map instance or its container.

However, I believe it may work if you add a key prop. You can try to see if it works.

```
      <MapContainer
        center={[IPdata.location?.lat, IPdata.location?.lng]}
        zoom={13}
        scrollWheelZoom={true}
        key={`${IPdata.location?.lat}${IPdata.location?.lng}`}
      >
```

**Updated**: There's another solution provided here using `setView` -> [React leaflet center attribute does not change when the center state changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64665827/react-leaflet-center-attribute-does-not-change-when-the-center-state-changes)

```
function ChangeView({ center, zoom }) {
  const map = useMap();
  map.setView(center, zoom);
  return null;
}

function Map({ center, zoom }) {
  return (
    <div className="map">
      <MapContainer center={center} zoom={zoom} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
        <ChangeView center={center} zoom={zoom} /> 
        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        />
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```