# how to change the center of the map container react-leaflet?

Tags: reactjs, geolocation, use-effect, use-state, react-leaflet

I want to be able to change the center of the react-leaflet map container by clicking the workout container which is an object that has the co-ordinates. I have shared all the states throughout the components using contextApi

//WorkoutData.js

```
export const WorkoutsData = [
  {
  id: 1,
  coords: {latitude: 56.27360151291927, 
  longitude:-82.84886256490017},
  },
  
  {
  id: 2,
  coords: {latitude: 49.27360151291927, 
  longitude: -75.84886256490017},
  },

  {
  id: 3,
  coords: {latitude: 39.27360151291927, 
  longitude: -79.84886256490017},
  }
];
```

//MapLocation.js
i have a main.js folder which has all the state variable and all the other components shares the variable using contextapi

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import "./styles.css";
    import { WorkoutsData } from "./WorkoutLocation";

    const MapLocation() => {
const [workouts, setWorkouts] = useState(WorkoutsData);
const [changedCoords, setChangedCoords] = useState({latitude: 0, longitude: 0})
const [workoutsClicked, setWorkoutsClicked] = useState(false);

     
 const locateWorkout = (id) => {
        setWorkoutsClicked(true)
        const findLocation = workouts.find((exercise) => {
          return exercise.id === id;
        });
        
        setChangedCoords({
          latitude: findLocation.coords.latitude,
          longitude: findLocation.coords.longitude
        })
      }



return(
<>
workouts.map((workout) => {
return(
<div key = {workout.id} className = 'workout-info'>
<div className = "workout-details">
<p>{workout.coords}</p>
</div>
</div>
)
})
</>
)
export default MapLocation;
```

//Map.js
i have a main.js folder which has all the state variable and all the other components shares the variable using contextapi

```
const Map = () => {
const[initialCoords, setInitialCoords] = useState({latitude: 0, longitude: 0})

 useEffect(() => {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        setInitialCoords({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude
        })
      })
    }
  }, [])



return(
<>
 <MapContainer center = { 
workoutsClicked !== true ? 
[initialCoords.latitude, initialCoords.longitude] : 
[changedCoords.latitude, changedCoords.longitude]}
zoom = {20}>

<TileLayer attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"/>

</MapContainer>
</>
)
}

export default Map
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React leaflet center attribute does not change when the center state changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64665827/react-leaflet-center-attribute-does-not-change-when-the-center-state-changes)

Answer (score 3):

`MapContainer` props in React Leaflet are immutable (https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map/#mapcontainer), therefore updating them after the map is initialised will have no effect.

You can use the [useMapEvent hook](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map/#usemapevent) to update the centre of the map when your `changedCoords` state changes. First of all define a function:

```
function UpdateMapCentre(props) {
  const map = useMap();
  map.panTo(props.mapCentre);
  return null;
}
```

Then add the following as a child of `MapContainer`:

```
<MapContainer ...>
  ...
  <UpdateMapCentre mapCentre={changedCoords} />
</MapContainer>
```

Because the props passed to `MapContainer` are immutable, you no longer need the ternary if statement to set the map centre (updating the map centre is now taken care of using `<UpdateMapCentre>`) and can just pass in the `initialCoords`.

```
<MapContainer center={[initialCoords.latitude, initialCoords.longitude]} zoom={20}>
  ...
</MapContainer>
```

See [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-leaflet-example-gmbabe?file=index.tsx) for a working demo. When you click on the latLng of a workout in the list below the map, the `changedCoords` state will be updated and the map will pan to the latitude and longitude of the workout.

Comment: Thanks Ian, this was the only right answer I found on internet. I works for me.