# React Leaflet map not Re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm encountering an issue with my React application where the Leaflet map component is not re-rendering even though the data it depends on has changed. Here's the structure of my code:
App.js

```
 let [ip_address,setIp] = useState();
   let [ipData, setipData] = useState({});
   let [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
   const inputRef = useRef("");
   //Get ip of user;
   const getData = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json");
    console.log(res.data);
    setIp(res.data.ip);
  }
   useEffect(() => {
    getData();
   }, []);

   useEffect(() => {
    if (ip_address){
      logData(ip_address)
      .then(values => {
        if (values.error_msg) {
          setErrorMessage(values.error_msg);
          setipData({});
        } else {
          setErrorMessage("");
          setipData(values || {});
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        setErrorMessage("An error occurred while fetching data.");
        setipData({});
      });
    }
   }, [ip_address])

 return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        {/* Header content */}
      </header>
      <Map className="Map" ipData={ipData} errorMessage={errorMessage} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Map.js

```
else  if (!Object.keys(ipData).length) {
        console.log("waiting");
    }
    else{
        const longitude = ipData["lat"]
        const latitude = ipData["lng"];
        const position = [longitude, latitude];
        const customIcon = L.divIcon({
            html:
            `
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="46" height="56" style="background: transparent;">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M39.263 7.673c8.897 8.812 8.966 23.168.153 32.065l-.153.153L23 56 6.737 39.89C-2.16 31.079-2.23 16.723 6.584 7.826l.153-.152c9.007-8.922 23.52-8.922 32.526 0zM23 14.435c-5.211 0-9.436 4.185-9.436 9.347S17.79 33.128 23 33.128s9.436-4.184 9.436-9.346S28.21 14.435 23 14.435z"/>
        </svg>    
            `,
            iconSize: [10, 16]
        })
        return (
            <MapContainer center={position} zoom={15}>
            <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            <Marker position={position} icon={customIcon}></Marker>
            </MapContainer>
        );
```

I expect the Leaflet map component to re-render whenever there's a change in the ipData prop passed to it. This includes changes in latitude and longitude coordinates. I chechek and it seems that the icon gets moved to the correct location but the map itself remains static, displaying the old location.

Comment: The useState variable names you chose are super confusing.  Consider `[ip, setIp]` and  `[location, setLocation]` - try to follow the `[x, setX]` convention.

Comment: It sounds like changing the Map Center did not re-position the map as you expected.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64665827/react-leaflet-center-attribute-does-not-change-when-the-center-state-changes